# How to click on the modify tab using python

Tags: python

The Properties editor has several categories.

among several tabs, I want to click on the modify tab using python.

[image]

but this seems not to be working.
How can I write a script that clicks various tabs of the Properties Editor?

Here is my code:

```
import bpy
bpy.context.space_data.context = 'MODIFIER'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to iterate through [`Screen.areas`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Screen.html?highlight=screen%20areas#bpy.types.Screen.areas), find the *Properties Editor* and [set the space](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html?highlight=area%20spaces#bpy.types.Area.spaces):

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

for area in C.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'PROPERTIES' and \
        C.object.type not in ('LIGHT_PROBE', 'CAMERA', 'LIGHT', 'SPEAKER'):
        # Set it the active space
        area.spaces.active.context = 'MODIFIER' # 'VIEW_LAYER', 'SCENE' etc.
        break # OPTIONAL
```

Further reading: [poll() failed, context incorrect?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add/6105#6105)

Comment: This answer is really what i wanted.
Thanks! ; )